# How to add an array in MongoDB databse?

Tags: database, python-3.x, mongodb, deep-learning, facial-identification

I am creating one facial recognition application using Facenet model. I want to store the face embedding computed by the model into MongoDB database that I have created using python. But I am getting an error while inserting the vector of length 128 into DB. The error is something like this

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 102, in command None, codec_options, check_keys) bson.errors.InvalidDocument: Cannot encode object: array([-0.05931559, -0.00251597, -0.0259446 , 0.04900783, -0.01918399)
```

I tried different things like changing the embedding vector into dict as

```
dict(embedding-vector)
```

but that also did not work.

Is there any way that it can be done? If yes how?

Or should I switch to another database?

Comment: Can you add the exact insert query you're using, and the exact error that you get?

Comment: *"... But I am getting error.."** - What is the **exact** error message? Either you are trying to insert something that does not serialize to BSON correctly and need to coerce into a "list of dict" or similar, or it's in fact a message telling you the [BSON Limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#bson-documents) was exceeded, in which case you need to find a different solution instead of storing in a single document. Or indeed it's just an error related to syntax. But we don't know unless you actually show the error and what you are doing.

Comment: Something like this 

`File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 102, in command
   None, codec_options, check_keys)
bson.errors.InvalidDocument: Cannot encode object: array([-0.05931559, -0.00251597, -0.0259446 ,  0.04900783, -0.01918399)`

Comment: I have used both `db.insert_one` and `db.vectors.insert` functions.